The norm $\|e^{A + B}\|$ for non-commuting matrices $A$ and $B$
Let $A, B \in C^{n \times n}$ be two matrices which are diagonalizable but not simultaneously diagonalizable. Equivalently, they do not commute. Then, in general, we have
$$
e^{A + B} \neq e^A e^B.
$$
My question is whether it can still be the case that
$$
\|e^{A + B}\| \lesssim \|e^A\| \|e^B\|
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is any matrix norm. If not, are there perhaps weaker versions of this which are true?
I attempted using the Lie Product formula
$$e^{A + B} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left( e^{\frac{A}{k}} e^{\frac{B}{k}} \right)^k$$
but then the norms of the diagonalizing matrices and their inverses appear with power $k$.

Diagonalizable matrices are dense in all matrices, so any inequality of this form is true for diagonalizable matrices iff it's true for all matrices. Sometimes this allows us to reduce facts about general (square) matrices to the diagonalizable case but in this case, as you say the norms of the diagonalizing matrices and their inverses appear, so I don't think it helps.
If $A, B$ are normal and $\| \cdot \|_2$ is the operator norm wrt the $\ell^2$ norm then we get
$$\begin{align*} \| e^{A+B} \|_2 &= \lim_{k \to \infty} \left\| \left( e^{\frac{A}{k}} e^{\frac{B}{k}} \right)^k \right\|_2 \\
 &\le \lim_{k \to \infty} \left\| e^{\frac{A}{k}} \right\|_2^k \left\| e^{ \frac{B}{k} } \right\|_2^k \\
 &\le \| e^A \|_2 \| e^B \|_2 \end{align*}$$
using $\| X \|_2^k = \| X^k \|_2$ for $X$ a normal matrix, which follows from $\| X \|_2 = \rho(X)$.
If $A, B$ are not normal then for $\| \cdot \|$ any submultiplicative norm we still have the generic bound
$$\| e^{A+B} \| \le e^{\| A \|} e^{\| B \|}$$
just by bounding each term in the Taylor series. We can get a tighter bound by calculating $\lim_{k \to \infty} \| e^{\frac{A}{k}} \|^k$. We have
$$\begin{align*} \left\| e^{\frac{A}{k}} \right\|^k &= \left\| 1 + \frac{A}{k} + O \left( \frac{1}{k^2} \right) \right\|^k \\
 &= \left\| 1 + \frac{A}{k} \right\|^k + O \left( \frac{1}{k} \right) \end{align*}$$
so, if we define
$$\mu(A) = \lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{ \| 1 + hA \| - 1 }{h}$$
to be the logarithmic norm associated to the norm $\| \cdot \|$, then we have, by definition, $\left\| 1 + \frac{A}{k} \right\| = 1 + \frac{\mu(A)}{k} + o \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)$, which gives
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left\| e^{\frac{A}{k}} \right\|^k = e^{\mu(A)}$$
which gives us the bound
$$\boxed{ \| e^{A+B} \| \le e^{\mu(A)} e^{\mu(B)} }$$
for any submultiplicative norm such that the logarithmic norm exists. If we take $\| \cdot \|_2$ again we have
$$\begin{align*} \| 1 + hA \|_2 &= \sqrt{\rho((1 + hA)(1 + hA^{\dagger}))} \\
 &= \sqrt{\rho(1 + h(A + A^{\dagger}) + O(h^2))} \\
 &= \sqrt{1 + h \, \lambda_{max}(A + A^{\dagger}) + O(h^2)} \\
 &= 1 + \lambda_{max} \left( \frac{A + A^{\dagger}}{2} \right) h + O(h) \end{align*}$$
so, writing $\text{Re}(A) = \frac{A + A^{\dagger}}{2}$ for the "real part" or self-adjoint part of a matrix, we get that the logarithmic norm of the operator norm is
$$\mu_2(A) = \lambda_{max}(\text{Re}(A))$$
in agreement with the calculation on Wikipedia. We have to switch from $\rho$ to $\lambda_{max}$ to account for sign, since $\lambda_{max}$ could be negative; to emphasize, $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest eigenvalue, not the spectral radius. This gives, for $A, B$ not necessarily normal,
$$\boxed{ \left\| e^{A + B} \right\|_2 \le e^{ \lambda_{max} (\text{Re}(A)) } e^{\lambda_{max}(\text{Re}(B)) } }.$$
This is not bad! This bound is tight if $A, B$ are skew-adjoint, for example, since then $e^{A + B}$ is unitary and the RHS is $1$. It's also tight if $A, B$ are scalar multiples of the identity. The generic bound $\| e^{A+B} \| \le e^{\| A \|} e^{\| B \|}$ is not tight in either of these cases.
Edit: Here's a counterexample showing we do not have $\| e^{A+B} \|_2 \le \| e^A \|_2 \| e^B \|_2$ if $A$ and $B$ are not normal in general. Take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = A^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $A + B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a self-adjoint matrix $J$ with eigenvalues $\pm 1$, so
$$\| e^{A+B} \|_2 = \rho(e^J) = e = 2.718 \dots $$
On the other hand, $e^A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ has norm $\sqrt{ \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2} }$ (WolframAlpha can compute singular values), and $e^B = (e^A)^T$ has the same norm, which gives
$$\| e^A \|_2 \| e^B \|_2 = \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = 2.\color{red}{6}18 \dots.$$
Inspecting our other bounds, we have $\| A \|_2 = \| B \|_2 = 1$ so the generic bound in this case is $e^2$, which is not tight, while $\text{Re}(A) = \text{Re}(B) = \frac{J}{2}$ has eigenvalues $\pm \frac{1}{2}$, so the logarithmic bound in this case is $e$, which is tight.
In general, if $A$ is normal then so is $e^A$, so $\| e^A \|_2 = \rho(e^A)$. The sizes of the eigenvalues of $e^A$ are the exponentials of the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A$, which are the eigenvalues of the real part $\text{Re}(A)$, so we in fact have
$$\| e^A \|_2 = e^{\lambda_{max}(\text{Re}(A))}$$
meaning that the multiplicative bound for $\| \cdot \|_2$ is actually a special case of the logarithmic bound for $\| \cdot \|_2$. In turn, the logarithmic bound is really a statement about a single matrix, not two matrices; it is equivalent to the bound $\| e^A \| \le e^{\mu(A)}$ given on Wikipedia, together with the fact that $\mu(A + B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$. The above identity tells us that the logarithmic bound for $\| \cdot \|_2$ is tight if $A + B$ is normal, which is quite nice; I think this means it's probably the best available bound for $\| \cdot \|_2$.
Edit #2: Actually the counterexample above gets much worse if we just scale $A$ and $B$ up. Namely if we consider $tA, tB$ for large $t$, then $tA + tB = tJ$ has eigenvalues $\pm t$, so
$$\| e^{tA+tB} \|_2 = e^t$$
grows exponentially in $t$. But $e^{tA} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ has norm at most $t + 1$, and the same is true for $B$, so $\| e^{tA} \|_2 \| e^{tB} \|_2 \le (t + 1)^2$. This means we can't have $\| e^{A+B} \| \le \| e^A \| \| e^B \|$ for any matrix norm if $A, B$ aren't normal, since we can both lower and upper bound $\| \cdot \|$ by a constant times $\| \cdot \|_2$, and we can generalize this counterexample to $n \times n$ matrices by taking $A$ to be a nilpotent Jordan block.

Thanks for this great and extensive reply! In the end it seems like my matrices are in some cases normal, in which case I can use the estimate. Regarding the estimate with the logarithmic norm, it is pretty nice, but in the end there is a huge gap between those estimates which take a norm of an exponential and those which take an exponential of a norm. The latter is always greater or equal to 1, while the former can recognize a possible decay of the semigroup.

@Robert: you're correct that the generic bound involving $e^{| A |}$ is quite bad. However the bound involving the logarithmic norm $e^{\mu(A)}$ is much better! It is not always greater than or equal to $1$ (since the maximum eigenvalue of the real part can be negative) and it is perfectly capable of noticing decay. The logarithmic norm is not a norm (it can be negative and it isn't homogeneous wrt multiplication by scalars in general); try calculating it in examples!

Sorry, isn't $\lambda_{\max}$ the largest singular value, which is always non-negative? Is it the largest eigenvalue instead?

I confused the notation! Oh wow that is amazing, I feel like $|e^A| \leq e^{\mu(A)}$ should be part of common knowledge when working with matrix exponentials! It's not easily found on Wikipedia.

@Robert: yes, I came across it while clicking around the Wikipedia articles about matrix norms, I'm amazed that this is the first time I'm seeing it because I agree it seems very fundamental.

The wikipedia page for logarithmic norm also states that $\alpha(A) \leq \mu(A)$ where $\alpha(A)$ is the maximum real part of an eigenvalue. I'm still dealing with a gap here as in that I would like to get back from the eigenvalues of the real part of $A$ to those of $A$. I basically have $|e^{V^{-1} D V}| \leq e^{\mu(V^{-1} D V)}$ and inside the diagonal matrix $D$ are my negative eigenvalues whose decay I want to extract. But I can not yet get rid of the diagonalizers $V^{1-}$ and $V$ without assuming them to be unitary, which would make $A$ normal.

Do you think there is hope for showing that $\mu(V^{-1} D V)$ is negative if $D$ is a diagonal matrix of negative values but $V$ do not have further assumptions?

@Robert: I would guess that that's not true and I'd bet you can find a $2 \times 2$ counterexample by playing around a bit. If you run into difficulties it would be good to ask as a separate follow-up question.

Hm yea you're probably right. Thanks a lot anyhow!

The closest thing I can think of is the Golden-Thompson inequality. The most popular version might be that for any two Hermitian matrices $A, B$ (since you want $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$), we have
$$
\operatorname{tr} (e^{A + B}) \leq \operatorname{tr}(e^A + e^B).
$$
A more general version will be for any unitarily invariant norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$,
$$
\Vert e^{A + B} \Vert \leq \Vert e^{A/2} e^B e^{A/2} \Vert.
$$

It's a start but Hermitian is unfortunately a much too strong assumption for my purposes.

Hongyi Li & Di Zhao "An extension of the Golden-Thompson theorem" prove this result for normal matrices. Not bad!
